# django i want to restrict pages with the user types

Tags: python, django

As I am new to django, i am getting stuck in many places.

I am working on some project for my company, where the users are divided in to three category.
In my User model, i have added three boolean files with name category1, category2 & category3, with any one True out of three fields.

Now i dont want category1 user to access category2  and category3 templates.

i am trying to check through function in views.py with below codes

```
def user_check(request):
    if not request.user.category1:
        if request.user.category2:
            return redirect('/category2')
        elif request.user.category3:
            return redirect('/category3')
```

Currently this is not helping me with the desired output.
Request to help me out with proper solution on this

I dont want users of category1 should able to view category2 & category3 pages. he/she should only be able to view pages designed for him/her ever if he/she tries to skip the flow and access it

Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/manager

Django Version: 2.2.5
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'intranet_app.apps.IntranetAppConfig',
 'intranet_app_agent.apps.IntranetAppAgentConfig',
 'intranet_app_supervisor.apps.IntranetAppSupervisorConfig',
 'intranet_app_manager.apps.IntranetAppManagerConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\sasank.sankaran\Desktop\web_project\intranet_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\sasank.sankaran\Desktop\web_project\intranet_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\sasank.sankaran\Desktop\web_project\intranet_venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\sasank.sankaran\Desktop\web_project\intranet_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\sasank.sankaran\Desktop\web_project\intranet_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.             if test_func(request.user):

File "C:\Users\sasank.sankaran\Desktop\web_project\intranet_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.             if test_func(request.user):

File "C:\Users\sasank.sankaran\Desktop\web_project\intranet_venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in inner
  257.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /manager
Exception Value: 'MyUser' object has no attribute 'user'
```

```
def category_check_to_block(user):
    return user.is_category2


@user_passes_test(category_check_to_block)
```

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    supervisor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    profile = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lob = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    span = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ojt_date = models.DateField()
    is_agent = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_supervisor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: i want only category1 user to view that page none of the other users should view that page, if they try to do that, it should redirect them to their pages

Comment: what exactly is not working with your current solution? "this is not helping me with the desired output" doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Also, have you looked at the [`user_passes_test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test) view decorator? That will protect your views.

Comment: I am getting error with the decorator 'MyUser' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: @dirkgroten - request your help in uderstanding the error. Also edited with the Traceback

Comment: the function you pass in the decorator receives the `MyUser` instance, not a `request`. Look at the example in the link I gave earlier (`def email_check(user)`).

Comment: @dirkgroten  -  Please help to find out my miss in the code edited.

Comment: Can you also post MyUser model attributes??

Comment: @abheet22 -  updated MyUser attributes